# where I can get Source Code for spring1.X or before

Tags: spring

I want to study spring ,but the new version is so big ,then I think perhaps the old is a good study material.somebody  can give a link or suggest? think you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check 
[source forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/springframework/) and here you can take the version that you need

Comment: think you for answer!